# Load a listener before the security or custom provider

Tags: authentication, symfony, listener, provider

I'm working on a custom provider that works exactly like a classical user form, however I have to give a second parameter to identify the user: a websiteId (I'm creating a dynamic website plateform).

So a username is no more unique, but the combinaison of username and websiteId it is.

I successfully created my custom authentication, the last problem I have is to get the websiteId from the domain thanks to a listener, it works, but infortunately the method that get the website id from the domain is loaded after my authentication provider, so I can't get the websiteId in time :(

I tried to change the listener priority (test 9999, 1024, 255 and 0, and negative numbers -9999, -1024, -255 etc...), in vain, it's loaded always after.

Here my code:

**services.yml:**

```
services:

    # Listeners _________________

    website_listener:
        class: Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Services\Listener\WebsiteListener
        arguments: 
            - @doctrine
            - @sybio.website_manager
            - @translator
            - %sybio.states%
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onDomainParse, priority: 255 }

    # Security _________________

    sybio_website.user_provider:
        class: Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WebsiteUserProvider
        arguments: [@website_listener, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

My listener is "website_listener", and you can see i use it for my sybio_website.user_provider as argument.

**WebsiteListener:**

```
// ...

class WebsiteListener extends Controller
{
    protected $doctrine;

    protected $websiteManager;

    protected $translator;

    protected $websiteId;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $entityStates;

    public function __construct($doctrine, $websiteManager, $translator, $entityStates)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->websiteManager = $websiteManager;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->entityStates = $entityStates;
    }

    /**
     * @param Event $event
     */
    public function onDomainParse(Event $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $website = $this->websiteManager->findOne(array(
            'domain' => $request->getHost(),
            'state' => $this->entityStates['website']['activated'],
        ));

        if (!$website) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->translator->trans('page.not.found'));
        }

        $this->websiteId = $website->getId();
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $websiteId
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->websiteId;
    }
}
```

$websiteId is hydrated, not in time as you will see in my provider...

**WebsiteUserProvider:**

```
<?php
namespace Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider;

// ...

class WebsiteUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;
    private $websiteId;
    private $userEntity;

    public function __construct($websiteListener, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->websiteId = $websiteListener->getWebsiteId(); // Try to get the website id from my listener, but it's method onDomainParse is not called in time
        $this->userEntity = 'Sybio\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\User';
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // I need the websiteId here to identify the user by its username and the website:
        if ($user = $this->findUserBy(array('username' => $username, 'website' => $this->websiteId))) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No record found for user %s', $username));
    }

    // ...
}
```

So any idea will be appreciate ;)
I spent a lot of time to set up my authentication configuration, but now I can't get the websiteId in time, too bad :(

Thanks for your anwsers !

**EDIT:**

I had also other files of my authentication system to understand, I don't think I can control the provider position when loading, because they're witten in the security.yml config:

**WebsiteAuthenticationProvider:**

```
// ...

class WebsiteAuthenticationProvider extends UserAuthenticationProvider
{
    private $encoderFactory;
    private $userProvider;

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @param UserCheckerInterface $userChecker
     * @param $providerKey
     * @param EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory
     * @param bool $hideUserNotFoundExceptions
     */
    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, UserCheckerInterface $userChecker, $providerKey, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, $hideUserNotFoundExceptions = true)
    {
        parent::__construct($userChecker, $providerKey, $hideUserNotFoundExceptions);
        $this->encoderFactory   = $encoderFactory;
        $this->userProvider     = $userProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function retrieveUser($username, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return $user;
        }

        try {
            $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);

            if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException('The user provider must return a UserInterface object.');
            }

            return $user;
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $notFound) {
            throw $notFound;
        } catch (\Exception $repositoryProblem) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException($repositoryProblem->getMessage(), $token, 0, $repositoryProblem);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**The factory:**

```
// ...

class WebsiteFactory extends FormLoginFactory
{
    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'website_form_login';
    }

    protected function getListenerId()
    {
        return 'security.authentication.listener.form';
    }

    protected function createAuthProvider(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProviderId)
    {
        $provider = 'security.authentication_provider.sybio_website.'.$id;
        $container
            ->setDefinition($provider, new DefinitionDecorator('security.authentication_provider.sybio_website'))
            ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProviderId))
            ->replaceArgument(2, $id)
        ;

        return $provider;
    }
}
```

**SybioWebsiteBundle (dependency):**

```
// ...

class SybioWebsiteBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
        $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new WebsiteFactory());
    }
}
```

**Security:**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            provider: website_provider
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            website_form_login:
                login_path:  /login.html
                check_path:  /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout.html
                target: /

    providers:
        website_provider:
            id: sybio_website.user_provider
```

Comment: Add a logger to your listener and have it generate a debug message when the event processor gets called then check the log file to see where it fits in.  I suspect something else is going on.  The session listener has a priority of 128.  Using a priority of perhaps 120 is what you want.

Comment: Did try with a negative priority? event dispatcher, use ksort for ordering listeners

Comment: Yes I tried to change the priority with negative numbers... Doesn't work, I just edited my question you will see my provider system, they're loaded via a factory, itself loaded before listeners, is there a way to change this ? Or another way to get the website id by a clean solution not with a listener ?

Answer (score 3):

Firewall::onKernelRequest is registered with a priority of 8 (sf2.2). A priority of 9 should ensure that your listener is called first (works for me).

I had a similar problem, which was to create subdomain-specific "Campaign" sites within a single sf2.2 app: {campaign}.{domain} . Every User has many Campaigns and I, like you, wanted to prevent a User without the given Campaign from logging in.

My solution was to create a Doctrine filter to add my campaign criteria to every relevant query made under {campaign}.{domain}. A kernel.request listener (with priority 9!) is responsible for activating the filter before my generic user provider tries to loadUserByUsername. I use mongodb, but the idea is similar for ORM.

The best part is that I'm still using stock authentication classes. This is basically all there is to it:

config.yml:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    document_managers:
        default:
            filters:
                campaign:
                    class: My\Filter\CampaignFilter
                    enabled: false
```

CampaignFilter.php:

```
class CampaignFilter extends BsonFilter
{
    public function addFilterCriteria(ClassMetadata $targetMetadata)
    {
        $class = $targetMetadata->name;
        $campaign = $this->parameters['campaign'];
        $campaign = $campaign instanceof Campaign ? $campaign->getId() : $campaign;
        if ($targetMetadata->hasField('campaign')) {
            return array('campaign' => $this->parameters['campaign']);
        }
        if ($targetMetadata->hasField('campaigns')) {
            return array('campaigns' => $this->parameters['campaign']);
        }
        return array();
    }
}
```

My listener is declared as:

```
    <service id="my.campaign_listener" class="My\EventListener\CampaignListener">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="9" />
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager" />
    </service>
```

The listener class:

```
class CampaignListener
{
    private $dm;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ($campaign = $request->attributes->get('campaign', false)) {
            $filters = $this->dm->getFilterCollection();
            $filter = $filters->enable('campaign');
            $filter->setParameter('campaign', $campaign);
        }
    }
}
```

'campaign' is available in the request here thanks to my routing configuration:

```
campaign:
    resource: "@My/Controller/CampaignController.php"
    type:     annotation
    host: "{campaign}.{domain}"
    defaults:
        campaign: test
        domain: %domain%
    requirements:
        domain: %domain%
```

.. and %domain% is a parameter from config.yml or config_dev.yml

Answer (score 0):

Like the response provide by benki07 it's a question of prority, you have to put your listener before the Firewall::onKernelRequest

Then, your listener will be called -> Firewall is call and your authentification listener are called with the webSiteId registered.

Comment: I'm agree with you but I don't know how to load my listener before my firewall, have you got an idea ? Documentation is missing, I tried to change the priority of my listener in vain, the method is always called after :s Is there a way to attach my listener on a "firewall event" ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the SecurityExtension.php The factories used do not have any sort of priority system. It just adds your factory to the end of the array, that's it.
Therefore it is impossible to put your custom authentication before that of symfony's security component.

An option may be to override the DaoAuthenticationProvider class paramater with your class. I hope that symfony2 will change from factories to a registry where you can add your custom authentication with a tag and a priority because this is not open/closed enough for me.