# Authentication with subdomain in mind

Tags: security, symfony, subdomain

We develop a multi-tenant system, where the client is identified by subdomain. Each client can have many users.

Most of the users only have access to one Subdomain, but there are users with access to multiple subdomains. Users can also have different roles on each subdomain.

So we need to check if the users has any roles on the current Subdomain. If not, authentication should fail.

Second, if a user has access to more than one Subdomain, he can switch between them. In this case the user's roles must be re-queried from the Database.

Currently we use a very hacky solution with a custom EntityProvider. Im very unhappy with that one.

P.S.: The Database behind the System is a legacy one, so **we cannot change it** to use ACL's or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to give specifics without seeing your schema, but my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893043/load-a-listener-before-the-security-or-custom-provider/15399038#15399038) describes how I used a `kernel.request` listener to activate a doctrine filter based on the requested subdomain. I use mongodb but it's basically the same for doctrine orm.

Comment: thanks, your answer and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879221/dynamically-adding-roles-to-a-user/8883269#answer-8883269) put me in the right direction.